# How to solve 'PusherAuthentication failed' error when trying to subscribe to a private channel with authorization using Soketi and Java Pusher client?

Tags: java, laravel, authorization, pusher

I need help with a Laravel application that uses Soketi and Java Pusher client to communicate with a Pusher server. I get a 403 error when I try to subscribe to a private channel using the Java Pusher client. The public channels work fine.

Here are some details:

- channels.php in Laravel:

```php
<?php

Broadcast::channel('private-{id}', function ($user) {
    return true; // always return true for testing
});
```

- BroadcastServiceProvider in Laravel:

```php
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]); // im using sanctum's tokens to authorize user
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

- Java Pusher client code:

```
public PusherConnector(String bearer) {
    try {
        PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();
        HttpChannelAuthorizer channelAuthorizer = new HttpChannelAuthorizer("http://localhost/broadcasting/auth"); // this is my broadcasting endpoint from Laravel's package
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer); // bearer token from sanctum
        channelAuthorizer.setHeaders(headers);

        options.setHost("localhost")
            .setWsPort(6001).setUseTLS(false).setChannelAuthorizer(channelAuthorizer);

        Pusher pusher = new Pusher("MY-PUSHER-APIKEY", options);
        pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                System.out.println("Pusher" + "State changed from " + change.getPreviousState() + " to " + change.getCurrentState());
                System.out.println(pusher.getConnection().getSocketId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Pusher" + "There was a problem connecting! " + "\ncode: " + code + "\nmessage: " + message + "\nException: " + e);
            }
        }, ConnectionState.ALL);

        PrivateChannel cn = pusher.subscribePrivate("private-" + bearer, new PrivateChannelEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationFailure(String s, Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Pusher" + "Authentication failed: " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String s) {
                System.out.println("Pusher" + "Subscription succeeded: " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(PusherEvent pusherEvent) {
                System.out.println("Pusher" + " -> Event received: " + pusherEvent.getData());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message, Exception e) {
                PrivateChannelEventListener.super.onError(message, e);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

- Output from the Java program:
  `PusherState changed from DISCONNECTED to CONNECTING null // the socket id ( not yet connected ) PusherState changed from CONNECTING to CONNECTED 6069547637.4178363411 // the socket id PusherAuthentication failed: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost/broadcasting/auth // the error`

**I have tried removing the sanctum’s auth middleware but it still gives the same error. I have also verified that the sanctum’s authentication works well with other parts of Laravel. I don’t understand why I can’t subscribe to the private channel with authorization. Any ideas?**

## ** EDIT! **

### So I've fixed it by watching the logics behind the laravel classes and tried to debug it by logging the requests, tried to modify the broadcasting's library code for debugging and heres what I've changed to make it work:

- the BroadcastServiceProvider

```
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ["auth:sanctum"]]); // to use the sanctum's auth and be able to get the current logged in user in the backend auth of Laravel's broadcasting
    }
```

- channels.php (Laravel's broadcasting channels file )

```php
Route::middleware(["auth:sanctum", TestyaMiddleware::class])->group(function () {
// TestyaMiddleware is a custom middleware for debugging ( i will remove that from my code later )
    Broadcast::channel('{id}', function ($user, $id) { // also removed the "private-" or "presence-" prefix ( because its not needed )
        return true;
    });
});
```

Thats all, i expect the problem happened because of the auth middleware isn't setted somewhere in the broadcasting channels route file or the broadcasting's auth route

Comment: Please if anyone needs any more info don't hesitate to comment too